# I have an Ender-3 Pro, the platform goes to the right rear every time I try to start a print job

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed

I have a Creality Ender 3 Pro, the platform goes to the right rear every time I try to start a print job. I do not know what to do. I am not very savvy on computer software, but I need some help.

I tried using the 3D pad with the same results.

I did a factory reset, using original controller, same results.

Back to the 3D pad, factory reset, same results.

I am using the Creality Slicer. When I select Auto Home, the platform returns to the front left side. When I try to print anything, it goes back to the right rear an sets there, dumping filament.

Comment: Can you tell us what happens when you try to autohome the device?  Also, what slicer are you using?

Comment: So the bed comes forward and the extruder to the right? What is your start G-code?  Does it print after going to the back-right? Or does it stay there?

Comment: Did your printer come with a test file? My Ender v2 did. If so, how does that print for you? If that works fine, then most likely, some setting in your slicer is telling your printer to move there. I found it to be a good idea to understand G-Code, and that allows you to reverse engineering problems that you run into. G-Code isn't hard, it's just a list of command