# Hotend moves to rear of build plate and extrudes

Tags: creality-ender-3

I have an Ender 3 and have a similar problem as mentioned in [I have an Ender-3 Pro, the platform goes to the right rear every time I try to start a print job](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/20687/).

My hotend and build plate reach temp, BLTouch homes centre of build plate, plate moves forward then "grinding noise" hotend moves to right at the rear of plate and starts to extrude filament then I have to reboot, reheat bed and hotend, select model and print this enables it to print. I have replaced the mother board, flashed with latest Marlin firmware: but this made no difference!

The fact that it prints after reboot suggest to me it can't be a firmware issue.

Comment: This is very hard to answer. You should create some basic G-code files manually to sort this out. E.g. to rule out slicing problems. Try, and update the answer by [edit].

Answer (score 1):

This is very hard to answer as there is not much information to solve this, read this answer as an advice to troubleshoot the problem. You should create some basic G-code files manually to sort this out to e.g. rule out slicing problems (this is where the question is not clear about).

Basically, the printer knows the coordinate system once it has homed all axes when properly configured in firmware. So, creating a basic file containing homing `G28`, leveling `G29`. Now, the print head should be at the last probed position. You now could add `G0 X0 Y0 F400` to slowly advance to the origin. You can add another line to move to the max X, Y position, `G0 X200 Y200 F400` (200 x 200 mm bed assumed). If the head positions correctly, your firmware is okay, you then need to find the solution in the slicing, else you need to fix the firmware settings.